# Access to coordinates through NSDictionary - iOS

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I would like to access coordinate values which are latitude and longitude.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"WellList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *cities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary *routes =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary *city =[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *locations =[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *locationInfo=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *localCities= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    city= routes [@"Routes"];
    NSLog (@"%@",city);
    localCities =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[city allValues]];
    locations =[localCities objectAtIndex:1];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try reading the documentation on NSDictionary.

Comment: Please look at my code, posted.

Comment: Which exactly are the results you want? Do you want the `coordinate` dictionary for all cities or a specific city?

Comment: OK, I looked at it. You're reading the file, good. Except that you're reading it as an array, and your screenshot clearly shows it's a dictionary.

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking how to access objects in a dictionary?

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *a=[[root objectForKey:@"Routes"]objectAtIndex:i]; but of course objectAtIndex is not a method of NSMutableDictionary but how am I going to loop it then?

Comment: I want to read all coordinates values and add them on the map. that is my final goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't understand how loading a .plist file works. Routes and Cities are being initialized to the same value, because you are loading both of them from the same file. So to access the latitude of Houston's Location 1, you would write

```
NSMutableDictionary *root = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSString* latitude = [[[[[root objectForKey: @"Routes"] objectForKey: @"Houston" ] objectForKey: @"Location 1"] objectForKey: @"coordinate"] objectForKey: @"latitude"];
```

Comment: Please, use the new syntax, `root[@"Routes"][@"Houston]`. And the root is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: NSString* latitude = [[[root[@"Routes"][@"Houston"] objectForKey: @"Location 1"] objectForKey: @"coordinate"] objectForKey: @"latitude"];  I am still getting an error from "root"

Comment: @Ben, error shows that there is no interface for root - (NSMutableArray for objectForKey)

Comment: Please see attached image on above. You can see what error says

Comment: @Casillas, I believe that's because of the typo Kevin pointed out. Root should be a dictionary, as it says in the Plist file you posted.

Comment: @casillas ***root is a dictionary. Declare and initialize it as one.***

Comment: @Ben, sorry for disturbing, last more question. How could I loop all the cities coordinates instead of hardcoding.

Comment: You can get all the keys in a Dictionary with the allkeys method of NSDictionary, then loop through them.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *a=[[root objectForKey:@"Routes"]objectAtIndex:i]; but of course objectAtIndex is not a method of NSMutableDictionary but how am I going to loop it then?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could only one step below. could you please look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752710/accessing-coordinates-in-plist-ios