# Accessing Coordinates in Plist - iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, plist

Instead of accessing specific latitude with hardcoded as shown in below

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"WellList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *root = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString* latitude = [[[[[root objectForKey: @"Routes"] objectForKey: @"Houston" ] objectForKey: @"Location 1"] objectForKey: @"coordinate"] objectForKey: @"latitude"];
```

I would like to use loop to access every single coordinate in my plist and add them into my NSmutableArray.

[image]

Comment: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *root = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *routes = [root objectForKey: @"Routes"];
NSArray *cities = [routes allValues];
for (NSDictionary *city in cities) {
    NSArray *locations = [city allValues];
    for (NSDictionary *loc in locations) {
        NSDictionary *coord = [loc objectForKey:@"coordinate"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[coord objectForKey:@"latitude"]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kumar, Could please check my dictionary again? I have just run it and return me "null".

Comment: Updated my answer. There was small mistake. With little efforts you could have also done it

Comment: Thanks a lot Kumar. Accepted your answer.